# In-App Purchase in Flutter iOS platform - no subscriptions returns from AppStore

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, in-app-purchase

I have a problem with retrieving my subscription list in a Flutter application.

- Official package in_app_purchase 3.1.5 is used
- Flutter version 3.7.6
- iOS 16.3.1
- Xcode 14.2
- Tested on a real device

**Steps have been already done:**

- Signing the Paid Applications Agreement and set up my banking and tax information in App Store Connect
- Creating non-consumable subscription (with id monthly_subscription) in app-store connect (in-app-purchase features). The subscription got the status “**Ready to Submit**”
- Adding In-App Purchase capability in Xcode (after this checked if In-App Purchase capability is selected at [https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/…](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/%E2%80%A6). Selected.)
- Creating **synced** .storekit configuration file. My subscription was successfully loaded from the store to Xcode.
- Selecting this new-created storeKit in the edit scheme window (product - scheme - edit scheme - run - options - storeKit configurations) (Xcode)
- Tried to run the project from Xcode.
- Tried to run the project from Android Studio
- Tried to publish the app in testFlight and check the behavior, but no result, the same.
- Product ID is correct. In AppStore, Xcode, and Android studio.

The code:

```
final bool isAvailable = await _inAppPurchase.isAvailable(); // true


if (Platform.isIOS) {
  final InAppPurchaseStoreKitPlatformAddition iosPlatformAddition = _inAppPurchase.getPlatformAddition<InAppPurchaseStoreKitPlatformAddition>();
  await iosPlatformAddition.setDelegate(ExamplePaymentQueueDelegate());
}

final ProductDetailsResponse productDetailResponse = await _inAppPurchase.queryProductDetails(_kProductIds.toSet());
```

But, queryProductDetails method returns ProductDetailResponse with ID "monthly_subscription" in notFoundIds list.

And that’s all.

I suppose that’s not a Flutter or package issue. I think I misunderstood something in the manuals… ?

Answer (score 1):

Check paid app agreement is signed or not, it is also an important step that just slips through the cracks

Comment: @crd, sheheryar501 is correct. I've been through all those steps and the only thing that were missing was paid app agreement. After that everything worked without the need on sending a build for review (just with the status Ready to Submit).

Comment: can you brief how to do it?